# Spurious (?) warning about string constants using a macro in OpenCL

Tags: string, macros, compilation, opencl

I use the following macro in my OpenCL kernel:

```
#define ided_printf(_format, ...) printf("(%u,%u,%u) " _format, get_global_id(0), get_group_id(0), get_local_id(0), __VA_ARGS__ )
```

and it works fine. However, when I compile it (I use AMD's APP OpenCL library on Win7), I get the following warning on each use of the macro:

```
argument of type "const __constant char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "__constant char *"
```

Why would I be getting that? After all, string literals are const's. And even if the OpenCL compiler doesn't make them const, why is the "(%u, %u, %u)" string const'ed while the other string (_format) is not consted?

I'm assuming this is a compiler bug; if it is, a workaround would be appreciated. Maybe some sort of cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on that AMD forum's [post](https://community.amd.com/message/1283186#comment-1283186), it is a bug. And yes a cast will do it as suggested in the same post:

```
printf((__constant char *)"%d\n", i);
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I tried a different cast first which didn't help me.